# android.support:appcompat-v7 and android.support:design is not working for api 30

Tags: android

hello i am making a app that requires api 29+ but

```
  'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
  'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
```

this two library is not supported api 29 or 30 how can i fix my issue?
heres my build.gradle (:app)

......................................................................................................................................................................................

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "uk.lgl.modmenu"
        minSdkVersion 17
        //noinspection ExpiredTargetSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.2"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        ndk {
            abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86'
        }
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        ndkBuild {
            path file('src/main/jni/Android.mk')
        }
    }
    ndkVersion = '23.1.7779620'
    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should switch to using the AndroidX versions of those libraries. Such as:

```
androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1
```

Comment: and for the com.android.support:design:28.0.0 ?

Comment: Check this mapping: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate/artifact-mappings 

You need to switch the design library to com.google.android.material:material